# mypy Error TypeVar with Value Restriction and Union of Unions / Optional Cannot Pass generic container type

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, mypy, union-types

So, the following example is obviously contrived but I tried to keep some verisimilitude to my actual situation. Now that I've whittled this down, I am sure I am missing something obvious. Consider a couple of types and a restricted Union:

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Optional, Generic, overload

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int)-> None:
        self.x = x
    def frobnicate(self) -> 'Foo':
        return Foo((self.x + 42) // 42)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, y: int) -> None:
        self.y = y
    def frobnicate(self) -> 'Bar':
        return Bar(self.y + 88)

MyType = TypeVar('MyType', Foo, Bar)
class Container(Generic[MyType]):
    val: Optional[MyType]
    def __init__(self, val: Optional[MyType]=None) -> None:
        self.val = val

def transmogrify(arg: Optional[MyType]) -> Optional[MyType]:
    if arg is None:
        return None
    else:
        return arg.frobnicate()

def extract_stuff(x: Optional[int], cont: Container[MyType]) -> Optional[MyType]:
    result: Optional[MyType]
    if x is None:
        result = None
    elif x == 88 or x == 42:
        result = transmogrify(cont.val)
    else:
        result = cont.val
    return result
```

When I try to type-check this with mypy, I get the following errors:

```
mcve3.py:32: error: Value of type variable "MyType" of "transmogrify" cannot be "Optional[Foo]"
mcve3.py:32: error: Value of type variable "MyType" of "transmogrify" cannot be "Optional[Bar]"
```

I cannot make sense of this. I suspect it is a problem of the many nested unions? Note, in my actual code, I am using a custom singleton enum `Null`, so wherever you see `Optional[Something]` it's actually `Union[Something, Null]`, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Now, if I remove the `Optional`, i.e. `Union`, it all plays nice:

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Optional, Generic, overload

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int)-> None:
        self.x = x
    def frobnicate(self) -> 'Foo':
        return Foo((self.x + 42) // 42)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, y: int) -> None:
        self.y = y
    def frobnicate(self) -> 'Bar':
        return Bar(self.y + 88)

MyType = TypeVar('MyType', Foo, Bar)
class Container(Generic[MyType]):
    val: MyType
    def __init__(self, val: MyType) -> None:
        self.val = val

def transmogrify(arg: MyType) -> MyType:
    if arg is None:
        return None
    else:
        return arg.frobnicate()

def extract_stuff(x: int, cont: Container[MyType]) -> MyType:
    if x is None:
        return None
    elif x == 88 or x == 42:
        return transmogrify(cont.val)
    else:
        return cont.val
```

What am I missing about Union's here?

Note, I've tried abstracting out a base-class, and having `Foo` and `Bar` derive from an abstract base class `class MyType(metaclass=abc.Meta)`, but a very similar error pops up.

Edit to Add:

```
(py37) Juans-MBP: juan$ mypy --version
mypy 0.620
```

Comment: @chepner I guess I'm just dense, can you elaborate a little bit? Because I'm using `Optional`, so how do restricted type vars work in `Union[MyType, NoneType]`?

Comment: I can't;  I just hadn't read your question carefully enough yet :)

Comment: This might have been fixed in newer versions of mypy? I was able to repro the problem using mypy 0.630, but the problem disappeared when I tried using mypy 0.641 (the latest).

Comment: @Michael0x2a ugh, very good to know, thank you!

Comment: @Michael0x2a oh man! That fixed it in my real use-case as well! Please feel free to post as an answer so I can accept and close!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was fixed somewhat recently in mypy. I was able to repro the problem in your first snippet by using mypy 0.630 but was unable to repro using both mypy 0.641 and the latest version of mypy on master.

I very loosely suspect the bug was fixed by https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/5699, but don't know for certain (and don't feel like checking, tbh).

You can monitor [mypy's blog](http://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/) if you'd like to be notified of future releases to avoid similar situations in the future. New releases are made roughly every 6 weeks to two months or so. -- the next release is slated to come out in roughly two weeks or so from time of writing.

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529693/mypy-error-overload-with-union-optional-overloaded-function-signatures-1-and) that I recently posted with a similar issue?