# Mypy error "Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types" when attempting to return float or sequence of floats

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to allow my class' `__getitem__` override to return either a single float or a sequence of floats depending on whether a string or sequence of strings argument is provided respectively. To do this I am using the `@overload` decorator from the [builtin typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) with two methods (and a third implementation method), however mypy is giving me the error *"Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types"* on the line of my first overload. My only guess as to why this could be happening is that `str` is being treated as a `Sequence[str]`, causing ambiguity.

```py
class SimulationResults:
    ...

    # Mypy error occurs here
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self: Self, names: str) -> float:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self: Self, names: Sequence[str]) -> Sequence[float]:
        ...

    def __getitem__(self: Self, names: str | Sequence[str]) -> float | Sequence[float]:
        def get_value(name: str) -> float:
            if name == self._time_var_name:
                return self._time[self._current_index]

            if name not in self._vars:
                raise KeyError(f"Variable '{name}' does not exist for this simulation")

            return self._vars[name][self._current_index]

        return (
            get_value(names)
            if isinstance(names, str)
            else tuple(get_value(name) for name in names)
        )
```

Could anyone clue me in on what's happening to cause this error, and if there are any ways to get around it? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222982/type-annotation-for-overloads-that-exclude-types-something-vs-everything-else) in addition to the linked dupe. You're correct that `str` is a subtype of `Sequence[str]` and this is the issue cause. In short, your definition is correct until someone uses `value: Sequence[str] = 'foo'` and passes it to your `__getitem__`, causing incorrect inference. This is far from perfect, because some function can return `'foo'` with annotation `Sequence[str]` as well (e.g. just to shorten the code - it's correct, after all).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy error, overload with Union/Optional, "Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529693/mypy-error-overload-with-union-optional-overloaded-function-signatures-1-and)

Comment: Thanks @STerliakov, it's slightly less user-friendly, but I'll change the overload to accept `tuple[str, ...]` instead of `Sequence[str]`

Comment: Yeah, you can use `tuple[str, ...] | list[str] | set[str] | frozenset[str]` to support at least most common builtin structures.