# Can individual List elements be type checked like items in a TypedDict?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm writing a type shed for some MicroPython code, one of the calls uses a list like a mutable tuple. If it were a tuple I could type it `Tuple[int, bool, int, memoryview]`, however it needs to be mutable and the API uses a list for this, therefore the best I have come up with is `List[Union[int, bool, memoryview]]`. Obviously that's not quite the same!

Is there something better?

Is there a List equivalent of TypedDict?

Comment: In the comments Georgy (thanks) suggested [Why can't List contain multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526516/why-cant-list-contain-multiple-types). In the answer to this question they say a list should be homogeneous and if you must use a union, i.e. my solution. However I can't change the interface; so the question still stands, is there a better solution that a union?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't List contain multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526516/why-cant-list-contain-multiple-types)

Comment: Thanks for that link, they are saying that you should not make a List of heterogeneous items. However it isn'y my interface, its from MicroPython, and consequently I can't change it! From a philosophical point of view I can see why they used a list; there is no mutable Tuple in Python, so what else could they do? Anyway is there a better solution than mine?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no better way than the one with `Union`. Somebody also advertised a 3rd-party [recordclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419745/7851470) as a mutable alternative to namedtuple.  Depending on the usage of the list, maybe, you could just replace it with the `recordclass`?