# How do you use Python type hints when you have messy input types?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function that expects a list of date-like objects, and I'm looking for a way to add good type hints.

```
def get_prices(dates):
   ...
```

The one I'm using now is

```
def get_prices(dates: list[str]) -> list[float]:
```

but I'm not 100% happy with this.

I could create a class `DateLike` and then do:

```
def get_prices(dates: list[DateLike]) -> list[float]:
```

but not sure if this is appropriate since the `DateLike` class would not be involved at all (except in the type hint).

At that point I could do:

```
def get_prices(dates: IterableOfObjectsThatCanBeCastToDatesByPandas) -> list[float]:
```

But then type hints have lost all meaning.

Comment: When you say date like objects can you give us the example of the types of objects? do you mean types like `datetime` and `timedelta`?

Comment: In this case my code supports date strings: `'2020-10-05'` or datetime objects: `datetime(2020, 10, 5)`

Comment: But my question is more generally: what options do I have when the built-in-types are not enough. I guess in Python 3.10 I could do `get_prices(dates:list[str|datetime])->list[float]`, but that still feels incomplete. I suppose I'm mixing up input validation with type hinting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't List contain multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526516/why-cant-list-contain-multiple-types)

Comment: No, but it's a good article - thanks.

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort I would recommend *not* accepting both. Accept `datetime` objects, and let the caller be responsible for creating them from strings.

Comment: How does that not answer your question? You said your function accepts strings or datetime objects... This is how you can type hint that...

Comment: Type hints dont do any validation, even if you put a type hint in your function that the parameter is a str, that doesnt stop the run time code passing it an int or a bool or any other type. I agree with @chepner. Accept only a valid datetime object and let the calling code ensure it creates that from the str

Comment: @mkrieger1, that was partly a joke. I could define a class with class named `IterableOfObjectsThatCanBeCastToDatesByPandas` just to use it as a valid type hint. Not saying you should :P

Comment: @Tomerikoo, my question was on how to use non-built in types in type hinting, not on how to combine built in types.

Comment: Type hints, and their use in a Union is not confined to built-in types...

Comment: @mkrieger1: Yeah, on reflection Pandas uses `DatetimeScalarOrArrayConvertible` as the typehint in `to_datetime`

Comment: Nice, I didn't find that before. You could use that then.

Answer (score 2):

It's not your function's job to parse date-like strings. It should *only* accept `date` objects, and let the caller be responsible for parsing strings first.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_prices(dates: list[datetime]) -> list[float]:
    ...

prices = get_prices([datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in datelikestrings])
```

The caller is also responsible for dealing with strings that cannot be parsed (i.e., when `strptime` raises an exception instead of returning an instance of `datetime`.)

Answer (score 0):

The typing module has a 'Union' class for this:

```
from typing import Union

def foo(bar: Union[str,int]):
    print(bar)
```

as of 3.10 you will be able to write:

```
def foo(bar: str|int):
    print(bar)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't reject strings that can't be parsed as dates.

Comment: Type hinting doesn't reject anything, it's a hint not a rule. You're right, you are mixing up type hints and input validation!

Comment: That's right. I'd like to indicate that if the input is a string then it needs to be a date, and for that maybe I could subclass `str` and use that in the typehint. But at that point I might as well just put it in the docstring. I mean, where does this end? What if I wanted to hint that the list should to be sorted? etc...

Comment: Type hints are not a panacea. Not everything *can* be encoded as a type (at least not in the relatively weak type theory implemented by PEP-484 and type checkers like `mypy`). Hint what you can, and leave the rest up to run-time tests.

Comment: And by "reject", I mean by a tool like `mypy`. Unless you are actually using a type checker that will *do* something, type hints *are* no better than a doc string.